# Oracle Trigger Issue (Toad)

Tags: oracle11g, triggers, database-administration

Oracle 11g/XE
Toad 12.7.1.11

I have a newly-installed db. Connected as SYS, created a user called 'jasons' with password and granted DBA. Disconnected and reconnected as 'jasons'. Then ran the following script:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE people_seq
  MINVALUE 0
  MAXVALUE 10000
  START WITH 0
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 20; 
 commit;


 create table people (PID number(10), FirstName varchar(20), LastName varchar(20));
 commit;


 alter table people add (constraint people_pk primary key (PID));
 commit;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER people_trig 
BEFORE INSERT ON people 
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  SELECT people_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.pid
  FROM   dual;
END;
commit;
```

When I run the script, everything goes well until the CREATE TRIGGER section. It throws:

```
ORA-04089: cannot create triggers on objects owned by SYS
```

I just created that very table as jasons! Can somebody please tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Duh...

When making a new connection in Toad there's a nice little dropdown box in the middle of the right-hand side that says "Connect As" with your choice of Normal, SYSDBA, and SYSOPER.

It defaults to SYSDBA -- but when you select 'Normal'... Well... The above script works just fine ;-)